# Can't insert russian language into mysql

Tags: java, mysql

**1.** show variables like `'%character%set%';`

[image: see image]

**2.** My table:

```
CREATE TABLE `t_languagetable` 
         ( 
                      `id`           INT(11) NOT NULL, 
                      `languagecode` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL, 
                      `countrycode`  VARCHAR(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL, 
                      `variant`      VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL, 
                      `language`     VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
                      `displayname`  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL collate 
                      'utf8_general_ci', 
                      PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
         ) 
         COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci' engine=innodb ;
```

**3.** My java code:

```
    Connection connect = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.99.211/"
                + databaseName + "?"
                + "user=" + username
                + "&password=" + password);

        statement = connect.createStatement();
        String displayName = "Русский";

        String insertSql = "INSERT INTO t_languagetable " +
                "VALUES (" + 1 + ", 'va', null, 'null', 'null' ," + "'" + displayName + "'" + ")";
        statement.executeUpdate(insertSql);
        System.out.println("insertSql: " + insertSql);
        connect.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("problem during the connection with the database!"+e);
    }
```

**4.** Results:

[image: russian character display as question mark]

Comment: On which system do the characters display as question mark? I suspect the problem is only on that system, which is probably configured for one of the ISO-8859 variants.

Comment: Hi Jim Garrison, I am using mariadb Server. version 10.1.22-MariaDB. version_compile_machine: x86_64 on linux red hat 7

Comment: Hi @Ravi I added  statement.executeQuery("SET NAMES utf8"); after connecting but which didn't make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED.

You have try to change method at insert time `setNString` in `displayname` Dont Change in database...!

try This way

```
Connection connect = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/"+databaseName+"?user="+username+"&password="+password);          
            PreparedStatement prep = connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO t_languagetable (id,languagecode,displayname) VALUES (?,?,?)");
            prep.setInt(1,7);
            prep.setString(2,"AA");
            prep.setNString(3,"Русский");

            prep.execute();
            System.out.println("Data Inserted.");
            connect.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("problem during the connection with the database!"+e);
        }
```

Comment: Yes, It works! but I wonder what is different between setString and setNString?

Comment: When you use `setString` at that you set value as u define in data base but `setNString` you can Sets the designated paramter  to the given String in your database. means you can set many character in database as supported by your database

Comment: In my project the setNString function not supported. Do you have any idea?

Comment: have you `java version` is lower then 1.6 ?, not supported

Comment: I find mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar

Comment: I am using jdk1.8.0_112

Comment: I successfully build with ant and deploy jar on my server. Java version on my server is: 
openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)

Comment: for more use full see : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Comment: Hi @Bhola I am using mariadb-java-client-1.5.9.jar and setNString is only alias of setString according to https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONJ-300. Russian character display still as question mark. Do you have another solution for my case

Comment: you can try mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin jar from http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar.zip it may be solved.

Comment: My project using mariadb-java-client so i can't change to mysql-connector-java.

Comment: Hi @Bhola Are there any way to insert without using setNString() function?

Comment: dude `mariaDB` and `mysql` is near by same, first change that to `mysql` and see. change just Only Jar File

Comment: understand that your connection String is same like `jdbc:mysql:\\ip or localhost , in mariaDB and mysql both have same connection string so they supported both jar

Comment: Hi @Bhola I found a solution at here https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONJ-406

Comment: your problem solved or Not...?

Comment: my problem solved !